# Эффективность использования двунаправленного списка вместо однонаправленного

Tags: c++

В чем состоит эффективность использования двунаправленного списка вместо однонаправленного с точки зрения системных ресурсов. То есть по отдельным видам ресурсов, какой вариант списка лучше, а какой хуже?

Comment: думаю выражу общее мнение, что контейнер для данных нужно выбирать исходя, в первую очередь, из свойств контейнера, а не из потребления ресурсов. Тобишь если вам необходима вставка в начало или итерация списка от конца в начало - то нет смысла мерять производительность одностороннего списка, так как он не подходит для этой задачи

Comment: Ресурс для двунаправленного списка конечно нужен больше,  если обе списка вы реализуете вполне тщательно, но ресурс не причем, тут важнее для чего они предназначены.

Answer (score 3):

Однонаправленный список лучше двунаправленного только тем, что у него один указатель, а не два. Если в списке хранятся мелкие объекты (4-8 байт), то это может быть существенно. Также, обновить два указателя и обновить один указатель может существенно сказаться на скорости.

Но двунаправленный список все же это хороший полноценный контейнер, а односвязный - очень сильно урезанный. К примеру, у него даже нет [size()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list).

Но если смотреть правде в глаза, то самый лучший список это std::vector. Да, да. Если он не очень большой (десяток-другой элементов), то по производительности сильно и сильно выигрывает. Если список побольше нужен, есть смысл посмотреть на [std::deque](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque).

Вот https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html люди меряют, что лучше.

И ещё - http://blog.davidecoppola.com/2014/05/cpp-benchmarks-vector-vs-list-vs-deque/

Comment: самый лучший список  не std::vector,  он лишь наиболее часто используемый.